# How to get De/Allocated time for azure VM in C# or powershell

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

How to get De/Allocated time for azure VM in C# or powershell. I know how to list all the VM's But not sure how i can see De/Allocated time for each VM

Answer (score 0):

This information is available in Azure Audit Logs. A feature of Azure Resource Manager (i.e. portal.azure.com - all resources created using "Resource Manager" and not "Classic").

You can read more about Azure Audit Logs and how to retrieve them here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-audit/